# What does negative R2 score mean in regression?

Tags: regression, svm

I am getting my R2 score for support Vector regression in negative. But when I tried to predict new results, It gives better performance than other algorithms? Is a negative R2 Score doesn't impact model performance?

Answer (score 3):

R2 score can be negative as stated in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html#sklearn-metrics-r2-score). R2 is not always the square of anything, so it can have a negative value without violating any rules of math. R2 is negative only when the chosen model does not follow the trend of the data.

It seems that your model may be giving better performance because of over-fitting.

Or maybe try running the r2 score function in this format:

```
r2_score(y_true, y_pred)
```

Comment: r2_score(y_true, y_pred) While giving this only I got a negative r2 score somewhat like -0.0005

Comment: It can be a case of over-fitting in the model. It can happen because of various reasons like small dataset and noise in the dataset. In order to convince yourself that the sklearn's r2_score function works properly and to get familiarised with it, I would recommend that you first fit and predict your model on training data only.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically it is possible. If there is no constant term in the linear regression, then the fit line won't neccessarily match the trend. This will lead to a possible negative R2 score, high variation in y (explained) than x (explanatory), and high bias in estimates of regression co-eeficients.
-taken from Charles Brooks 2019 version